# What is for PHP_ZTS predefined constant in PHP?

Tags: php

There is a [predefined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) `PHP_ZTS` available from PHP 5.2.7, but there is no documentation for it in the manual.

Can anyone explain what's its purpose?

Comment: http://www.phcomp.co.uk/PackagesBackports/php-zts.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PHP_ZTS` is predefined constant which returns whether `Zend Thread Safety` (ZTS) is enabled or not.

> PHP_ZTS (return value of "0" (false) indicates compiled php is non thead safe)

Some extensions need `ZTS` enabled to work properly with `PHP`; it's enabled using the option:

```
--enable-maintainer-zts
```

at PHP build time.